# How to disable systemd-logind from handling lid close actions?Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, 15.04, systemd-logind

I want do disable logind from handling lid close actions, because my MacBookAir uses sometimes 45 seconds to suspend after closing lid. I have diabled this in settings editor in Xubuntu before, and then my MacBook suspended right away with no problems. This has only happen in Ubuntu 15.04. And logind is the problem. I want to know how to disable logind from handling lid close actions in Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. Look for help in the [man page of logind.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man5/logind.conf.5.html)

Specifically, you want to change **HandleLidSwitch** to **ignore** in the above mentionned file. But then when closing the lid, no action will be taken and the laptop will not go to sleep. This might not be what you want.

Comment: I have checked i multiple times. Nothing there i found that could help me. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Fixed it in logind.conf